# Laravel Nova 3.23.0 Installation issue 'CreateNova' & 'Nova' is not defined

Tags: laravel, installation, laravel-nova

I am installing Fresh Nova in my new Laravel project, following all the steps in the documentation as stated.

After following those steps and logging in to Nova I am unable to see Nova Dashboard.

The following error is displayed in the console:

[image: screen shot of browser console log]

Comment: Have you tried publishing the vendor folder using `publish` command?

Comment: yes I did that.

Comment: this was an old bug, If you edited some sources, you should run ``php artisan nova:publish``, if that doesn't work then remove all assets manually. If that doesn't work, then try reinstalling nova again.

Comment: @HéctorWilliam I actually tried all these things but it doesn't work either. There is some issues related to assets compilation